# AS3: Design Theory, change frame of MC for each subsequent frame that it appears on?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

I feel like my question is fairly basic, but I'm going about it in a difficult manner.

```
charOneSprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, displayCharParts1);

function displayCharParts1(e:Event):void
{
    trace(charOneSprite.currentFrame);
    charOneSprite.weaponSpr.gotoAndStop(charOne.Weapon);
    charOneSprite.secWeaponSpr.gotoAndStop(charOne.SecWeapon);
}
```

I have a MovieClip that has an animated character performing different actions. Depending on what "equipment","weapons",etc that the player has equipped will display the correct MC frame of that specific equipped part. Essentially individual MC's for arms, weapons, heads, torsos displayed in different ways across the animation, using multiple different MC's for the same part, though the instance would still be called "leftArm", etc. Since I've extensively animated the frames of the movieclip already, I was hoping I could just build some code to adapt to it (as opposed to re-animating using strictly AS3).

Though it is not efficient (there is literally a gotoAndStop on every frame the sprite is animated differently) it works.... mostly. I'm having

```
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."
```

on several frames that actually DO contain the instance of the specific movieclip I'm targeting. There are no duplicates or anomalies I can find on the frames it specifies, and the error flags with some inconsistency, sometimes across different frames each time I run it (causing blinks of blank mc's).

I feel like there is a better way to go about the design of this, without having to change the animation I've already made. I'm open to any and all suggestions to improve my form. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using frames like that.  Use them for animations - stuff that will play - like frames in a movie.  Without changing your code much, you can switch to using visible which is much better than using frames:  charOneSprite.weaponSpr.weaponOne.visible = true;

Comment: Ah, see, that's the thing. The character is 'animated' in the sense that he could be swinging a weapon or using his arms, all done with frames, playing out the action. I just need to set all the frames in that animation to display the same thing. I don't think visible = true would work in this case, given that there will be several varieties for each MC (different color armor, different weapons) and to make each one visible or not would be inefficient. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: Keep thinking about it.  You shouldn't repeat any code.  For example, you set clip characterOne.weaponOne to handGun or whatever just once - characterOne.weaponOne.handGun.visible = true;  You can animate characterOne.weaponOne or characterOne and it'll keep showing handGun for that instance of weaponOne (characterOne's weaponOne).